# Function return value as excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

I am trying to convert a formula created by function to return as a formula instead of function brackets. As shown in screenshot attached.

```
Function f2t2(rng As Range) As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    jGetFormula = rng.Formula
    jGetFormula = Replace(jGetFormula, "(", """" & "(" & """" & "&")
    jGetFormula = Replace(jGetFormula, ")", "&" & """" & ")" & """" & "&")
    jGetFormula = Replace(jGetFormula, "+", "&" & """" & "+" & """" & "&")
    jGetFormula = Replace(jGetFormula, "-", "&" & """" & "-" & """" & "&")
    jGetFormula = Replace(jGetFormula, "*", "&" & """" & Chr(215) & """" & "&")
    jGetFormula = Replace(jGetFormula, "/", "&" & """" & "/" & """" & "&")
    jGetFormula = Replace(jGetFormula, "^", "&" & """" & "^" & """" & "&")
    jGetFormula = Replace(jGetFormula, "&&", "&")

    If (Right(jGetFormula, 1) = "&") Then
        jGetFormula = Left(jGetFormula, (Len(jGetFormula) - 1))
    End If

    'MsgBox jGetFormula
    'recalcualting other formulas in the excel
    Application.Volatile

    'Returning to excel
     f2t2 = jGetFormula

    'f2t = jGetFormula
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Function
```

I am trying to convert a formula created by function to return as a formula instead of function brackets. As shown in screenshot attached:

[image: screenshot]

```
Sub Formula_Edit(Optional endAll As Boolean = False)

MsgBox "3"
Range("T101").Value = 5
If endAll Then End
MsgBox "4"
End Sub

Function call2()
MsgBox "1"
Call Formula_Edit(True)
MsgBox "2"
End Function
```

Comment: You cannot use a UDF (user defined function) to return a formula into a cell. A function can only return values but not a formula. That means your function `f2t2` can return a result as text or as number for example but it cannot write a formula into a cell.

Comment: Thanks PEH for quick response, basically I want to show the values used in the formula i.e., I want to show 1×1.4+2-(1.4/2) results 2.7, so is there any way around to do this.

Comment: Are you not just looking for the [`FORMULATEXT`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-formulatext-function) function, available from Excel 2013 onwards?

Comment: @JvdV no basically he wants to do a formula to text and replace the addresses with the actual values.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, right, so more likely looking for [`Range.Precedents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents) then?

Comment: Can you include more information on the forms your formula may have. Would it always be single cells that get multiplied, added or devided? Whole ranges are easy to reference, but swapping those for actual values is not.

Comment: @JvdV yes but the issue is `Precedents` does not work properly in a UDF so we cannot use that to replace the addresses. I think the only way is to parse the formula for addresses to replace them.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is right. whether Range.precedents can be used. But I need as a function as I may be having several locations where I want to show similar calculations. So any thing like function called to another function or function passing as string to another module which does it.

Answer (score 0):

As JvdV pointed out there is the [Range.Precedents property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents) which returns all cells the range depends on. So we can loop through these cells and take their addresses to replace them with values (see below example).

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("H19")

    Dim Output As String
    Output = "'" & rng.Formula
    Output = Replace$(Output, "*", "×")

    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng.Precedents
        Output = Replace$(Output, r.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), r.Value) 'H16
        Output = Replace$(Output, r.Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=False), r.Value)  'H$16
        Output = Replace$(Output, r.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=True), r.Value)  '$H16
        Output = Replace$(Output, r.Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True), r.Value)   '$H$16
    Next r

    Range("H20").Value = Output
End Sub
```

*<sup>Procedure 1: This can convert simple formulas but you cannot use it in a UDF!</sup>*

**But this does not work in a user defined function, only in a procedure that is eg called by a button or shortcut.** Also this does only work for simple formulas like you showed.

For example it can convert

```
=H16*H17+H18-(H17/H18)
```

into

```
'=1×1.4+2-(1.4/2)
```

But if you have a more complicated formula like

```
=Sheet2!H16*Sheet3!H17+H18-(H17/H18)
```

This approach cannot be used anymore. Also if the formula contains other functions that accept ranges (eg `SUM()`), your whole idea cannot work anymore.

Because for example `=SUM(H16:H18)` cannot be converted into values.

---

If you need to do this in a UDF (user defined function) this would only be possible to be solved by parsing the formula. But be aware that this is **much** more complicated and a way too broad to be answered here.

---

Alternative approache that may work:
Use named ranges for your values. For example:

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: The cell H17 with value `1.4` is named `Mass` and the cell H18 with value 2 is named `SpeedOfLight` (named ranges).</sup>*

The formula for the cell H19 "Energy" can then be written as `=H17*H18^2` or because we use named ranges `=Mass*SpeedOfLight^2`.

Then you can use the `FORMULATEXT()` function to turn this formula into text and if you like replace `*` with `×`.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: The formula used is: `=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(H19),"*","×")`.</sup>*

Comment: Thanks for suggesting alternate procedure.

Comment: @afroztulip added another alternative idea that might result in some readable formula and is much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned by Peh, here a solution with parsing the formula.
This solution may suit your needs but is not full proof. Some functions in the functions will be evaluated as one value.

```
Function f2t2(rng As Range) As String
    x = rng.Formula
        For Each del In Array(";", " ", ".", "<", ">", "+", "-", "=", "/", "\", "*", "^") '":","(", ")"
            x = Replace(x, del, "|")
        Next del
            arr1 = Split(x, "|")
            arr2 = arr1

        For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
            On Error Resume Next
            arr2(i) = IIf(Application.Evaluate(arr1(i)) = "", "0", Application.Evaluate(arr1(i)))
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i

    x = rng.Formula
        For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
            x = Replace(x, arr1(i), arr2(i))
        Next

    f2t2 = x

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @EvR. The code which I posted earlier yields similar results if I replace f2t2 = jGetFormula with f2t2 = Evaluate(jGetFormula). However the code you posted has some tweaks, If my cell T100 = 2 and T101 = 3 and formula is =(T100*10^2)/T101 function is yielding =(T100*10^2)/3 instead of =(2×10^2)/3.

Comment: Yes, you have to tweak the array a bit to serve your needs, add in this case ,"(", ")" to the array ( this will make worksheetfunctions in your formula not working properly)